# StructureMap - Register a singleton for multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I want to register some animals as singletons, so I wrote a structure map registry with the following code:

```
this.For<ILion>.Use<Lion>().Singleton();
this.For<IElephant>.Use<Elephant>().Singleton();
```

*ILion* and *IElephant* derive from *IAnimal* and I also want a possibility to get all animals at once. I tried:

```
this.For<IAnimal>.Add<Lion>().Singleton();
this.For<IAnimal>.Add<Elephant>().Singleton();
```

but that gives me two different *Lion* instances for each interface:

```
public AnyConstructor(ILion lion, IEnumerable<IAnimal> animals)
{
    // lion == animals[0] should be true here, but is false
}
```

How can I tell structure map to only instantiate **one** *Lion*?

Comment: are they the same lion instances?

Comment: how does it "give" you 2 lion instances?

Comment: please show the code that returns the 2 instances

Comment: can you manually create a `Lion` and register that instance as a singleton?

Comment: Yes I could but that's what I do not want to since a *Lion* has a lot of injected constructor parameters. Resolving those is why we use structure map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is that you are getting two different Lion instances, you can use the `Forward<TFrom, TTo>()` method like this in your Registry:

```
this.For<ILion>().Use<Lion>().Singleton();
this.For<IElephant>().Use<Elephant>().Singleton();
this.Forward<ILion, IAnimal>();
this.Forward<IElephant, IAnimal>();
```

Then, to get all the IAnimal instances use `GetAllInstances<T>()` method like this:

```
var lion = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILion>();
var elephant = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IElephant>();
var animal = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IAnimal>();
```